# Specify name of Oracle IDENTITY sequence?

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, oracle12c

I’m using Doctrine to connect to an Oracle database. At the moment I’m just testing locally.

However, when we move to production it seems there’s no way to specify the IDENTITY sequence name so it’s mirred in production and local. If they’re not the same it will make things quite difficult when testing before sending to production.

Is there any way to specify the Sequence name for the IDENTITY column?

Comment: Do you need to use an `identity`?  Could you create a sequence and set the `nextval` of the sequence as the default for your column?  That basically does the same thing but lets you name the sequence explicitly.

Comment: Identity columns are introduced in 12c. If your testing environment is 12c and you use identity columns, then the production should be at least 12c as well. Otherwise, the whole concept just doesn't make sense. You shouldn't use identity columns if production is, for example, 11g, as it just won't work and you'll have to rewrite everything and test again. So: which versions are really involved?

Comment: They are all 12c. However I noticed that trying to marry up a sequence names in Doctrine across all 3 would mean manually changing the sequence names in the Entity classes for each environment (due to IDENTITY) using system generated names). The first comment I think is the answer to this. Just wondered if anyone else had experience with this. I’m fairly new to Oracle but even at a glance the IDENTITY column seems impossible to use across multiple environments if they all generate random sequence names.

Comment: So after a little playing around with Doctrine it seems that It does support IDENTITY as the @GeneratedValue but I can’t see that anywhere in the docs. I’ll make sure today and update the answer. This would mean I don’t have to specify the sequence name in Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

Data_default column provides the default value (long) of this column.  If you convert it to string (using dbms_output.put_line), you will get the name of the seqence.

select data_default
from all_tab_columns
where table_name ='<TABLE_NAME>'
and column_name='<COLUMN_NAME>';

Comment: Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.